# Dr Seuss style prose advanced mathematics text

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

There are a number of Dr Seuss style mathematics books for elementary school mathematics. It occurred to me that there is no particular reason that that style of prose couldn't be adapted to a playfully worded advanced math text book. I'm not particularly attached to what topic, I'm just thinking something along the lines of an advanced undergrad or graduate level text, has any one seen such a book?

It seems like it would be a fun project to do with some notes that you want to write up but want to make a bit more interesting to read. Assuming that someone hasn't already done just that.

Comment: $\widehat{\operatorname{Cat}}$

Answer (score 10):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but exercise 130 on page 135 of Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis* asks the reader to "Write jingles at least as good as the following":

[image: Topology Jingles]

It's a challenge question.

Answer (score 8):

A good fit for what you asking about are the books by [Lillian Rosanoff Lieber (1886-1986)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lillian_Rosanoff_Lieber). I've listed most of them below, maybe all of them. All of her books that I've actually looked at (probably about 6 or 7) are written in a distictive poetic style. Several have been recently reprinted, and in the U.S. they can often be found in public libraries that still have older books on the shelves.

[**Non-Euclidean Geometry Or Three Moons in Mathesis**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Y8D3U2) (1940)

[**Galois and the Theory of Groups: A Bright Star in Mathesis**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003TN483A) (1941)

[**The Education of T.C. Mits**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1589880331) (1944/2008)

[**The Einstein Theory Of Relativity**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1178489728) (1945/2008)

[**Take a Number: Mathematics for the Two Billion**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00225NY0E) (1946)

[**Mits Wits and Logic: What Modern Logic Means to You**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AROE28U) (1947)

[**Infinity: Beyond the Beyond the Beyond**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1589880366) (1953/2007)

[**Lattice Theory: The Atomic Age in Mathematics**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007T2MA6Y) (1959)

[**Human Values and Science, Art and Mathematics**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393063399) (1961)

[**Mathematics: First s-t-e-p-s**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007T3S4TU) (1963)