# Looking for a specific female maths writer

Tags: reference-request, education

This is going to be an annoying question, but I have to ask it as it is annoying me. I once read a book on infinity that was written by an American female maths writer. She was very easy to read and a great explainer of concepts. A very distinct aspect of her books were that there were only a few words on each line to assist with reading quickly. Can anyone tell me her name?
Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

"From Zero to Infinity: What Makes Numbers Interesting" by Constance Reid?  The author of a great book on David Hilbert and one on Richard Courant.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are thinking of this book:

Lillian R. Lieber, "Infinity," Rinehart, New York, 1953.

Republished years later as:

Lillian R. Lieber, "Infinity," Paul Dry Books, Philadelphia, 2007.

Comment: (+1) It's somewhat amazing that no one seeing this question thought of Lieber's book when the OP wrote "*A very distinct aspect of her books were that there were only a few words on each line to assist with reading quickly.*" As for myself, I apparently didn't see this question when it originally appeared, although interestingly the question was asked only a month after I gave [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/712609/13130).

Answer (score 0):

But if she was Hungarian then Rózsa Péter :"Playing with Infinity: Mathematical Explorations and Excursions", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B3zsa_P%C3%A9ter